# D3 zoomable pack chart update

Tags: d3.js

I'm working on this code found in this [example](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/pack-hierarchy.html). I'm using it in an angular directive.

```
function _directivePackChart() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        var w = 600,
            h = 500,
            r = 500,
            x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, r]),
            y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, r]),
            node,
            root;

        var pack = d3.layout.pack()
            .size([r, r])
            .value(function (d) { return d.size; })

        var vis = d3.select("svg")
            .append("svg:g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w - r) / 2 + "," + (h - r) / 2 + ")");

        var data = scope.ChartData;
        function drawChart() {
            node = root = data;

            var nodes = pack.nodes(root);

            vis.selectAll("circle")
                .data(nodes, function (d) { return d.path;})
              .enter().append("svg:circle")
                .attr("class", function (d) { return d.children ? "parent" : "child"; })
                .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
                .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; })
                .attr("r", function (d) { return d.r; })
                .on("click", function (d) { return zoom(node == d ? root : d); });

            vis.selectAll("text")
                .data(nodes, function (d) { return d.path;})
              .enter().append("svg:text")
                .attr("class", function (d) { return d.children ? "parent" : "child"; })
                .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x; })
                .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y; })
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .style("opacity", function (d) { return d.r > 20 ? 1 : 0; })
                .text(function (d) { return d.name; });
        };
        drawChart();
        d3.select(window).on("click", function () { zoom(root); });
        scope.$watchCollection('ChartDataUpdateCounter', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            drawChart();
        });

        function zoom(d, i) {
            var k = r / d.r / 2;
            x.domain([d.x - d.r, d.x + d.r]);
            y.domain([d.y - d.r, d.y + d.r]);

            var t = vis.transition()
                .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750);

            t.selectAll("circle")
                .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.x); })
                .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.y); })
                .attr("r", function (d) { return k * d.r; });

            t.selectAll("text")
                .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.x); })
                .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.y); })
                .style("opacity", function (d) { return k * d.r > 20 ? 1 : 0; });

            node = d;
            d3.event.stopPropagation();
        }
    }
};
}
```

The problem I'm running into is in the drawchart method, I have enter() method. How should I convert this code so that it handles updates too ? Note that the drawchart is triggered from watch. This is a drill down use case, as users drill down, more nodes are added to the selected node.

When the drill down happens, I remove the size property on the selected node and add child nodes. When I recompute the nodes, I'm suspecting if the parent node has newer cx,cy,r properties. But since no update is defined, its still using its old properties and looks weird.

I'm new to D3 & SVG.

Answer (score 0):

I turned out to be simple. I just had to break the line like this

```
 var circle = vis.selectAll("circle")
                    .data(nodes, function (d) { return d.path; });

                circle.enter().append("svg:circle")
                circle.exit().remove();

                circle.attr("class", function (d) { return d.children ? "parent" : "child"; })
                    .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
                    .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; })
                    .attr("r", function (d) { return d.r; })
                    .on("click", function (d) {
                        return zoom(node == d ? root : d);
                    });
```